# AVD stays stuck on "Android is starting"

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop, android-virtual-device

I've **no issue launching a Wear VD** but I can't get a normal Android to start...

Working on Windows 7 - 64 bits, with Intel Core 2 Duo E8200 (so no 64 bits emulation) and 6Gb RAM.

When I try to launch a virtual device with [avd](/questions/tagged/avd),

If I try with `Intel Atom (x86)`, I get stuck on the Android screen :

[image: Intel Atom (x86)]

---

Using `Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)`, it stays stuck on the final loading screen :

> Android is starting
>
> Starting apps.

[image: Google APIs Intel Atom (x86)]

---

Here are the settings :

[image: Google APIs Intel Atom x86 - settings]

I've tried to :

- lower the emulated RAM under 768 Mb as advised (stuck earlier (at `Optimizing app N of 74`))
- maximise emulated RAM (2048 Mb)

but that doesn't fix the problem...

**Any ideas?**

Comment: change the ram size to 1gb and check? Have you installed HAXM in your machine

Comment: Yes, HAXM is installed. I tried to set RAM to 1gb but still got the same issue... :/

Comment: set ram size to 768M as shown in warning

Comment: @HourGlass : It just got suck ealier (at `Optimizing app 67 of 74`). I tried with the max RAM allowed (2048) but still got stuck on `Starting apps.`

Comment: use host GPU in emulator option and check

Comment: @HourGlass : I tried but same result! I checked every update I could do (drivers, SDK, ...) still same result after multiple reboot! :'(

Comment: don't use atom x86 try someother architecture instead ?

Comment: I've already tried, but this one is the closer I get from a functioning android. I've tried ARM EABI, Atom, and all Google APIs for API 21,22 and 23... And I can't get a 64 bits image because my processor can't handle it...

Comment: Have you tried using a genymotion virtual device?

Comment: have you tried Android Studio?

Comment: @MarkYisri : Yup, and in Android Studio, you use AVD (Android Virtual Device) so it's the same thing! ;)

Comment: @DarshanMiskin : Same issue with Genymotion...

Comment: looks like an issue with ram availability itself, have faced such issues in my college's low end pcs. try reducing the avd ram to 500mb or lesser. how much is your pc ram btw?

Comment: @DarshanMiskin : 6 Gb of RAM, so even with 2048 Mb I'm not even at 80% usage... I just launched AVD with less than 500 Mb RAM, will see...

Comment: @DarshanMiskin : It just got suck earlier (at `Optimizing app 56 of 74`).

Comment: Can you try an Android 2.3 x86 image for testing? This sounds like slow emulation.

Comment: @MarkYisri : Yup, that work with Android 2.3 x86! A good start, but not sure how I'll test on more advanced API...

Comment: @R3uK started a room with you for discussion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay its not the previous HAXM errors of 2015 as it was escalated with Intel and they fixed it asof summer 2015:

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/536330

But that was a different set of CPUs than the on you listed

Probably since you have Windows 7 64-bit the feature may be disabled in your BIOS. The way to enable it in BIOS will be different due to the OEM of the laptop or desktop computer but usually can be found at the OEM's website as its a common asked question.

Comment: Thx, I'll check that closer! But as I'm running Android Wear VD with no issue, I'm fairly certain that virtualisation option is already activated in my BIOS! I'll get back to you soon

Comment: I check and it was indeed already activated (as I was able to launch a virtual Android Wear), so that didn't solve but thanks for the research! ;)

Comment: I gave the bounty by default here, but the problem isn't solved... (No hard feeling ;) ). @MarkYisri suggested to test with Android 2.3 and it works, so we just started to identify the issue more than here.